# Presto aggregate function UDF throws java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when called with nonempty GROUP BY set, but is fine otherwise

Tags: presto

I wrote a user defined aggregate function for which I'm seeing the following behaviour.  A query like the one that follows works fine,

```
SELECT
    my_aggregate_function(column)
FROM table
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT
    a,
    my_aggregate_function(column)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    1
```

throws a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.  I expect that I must have messed something up when writing my aggregation function.  The function is an implementation of the hyperloglog algorithm, but modified so that it ingests data from a base64 encoded format that is logged from another system:

```
@AggregationFunction("hll_merge")
public final class HyperLogLogAggregation
{
    private HyperLogLogAggregation()
    {
    }

    // This function tells us how to process rows into the accumulator state
    @InputFunction
    public static void input(@AggregationState HyperLogLogState state, @SqlType(StandardTypes.VARCHAR) Slice registers)
    {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(registers.getBytes());
        DynamicSliceOutput bytesToDeserialize = new DynamicSliceOutput(decodedBytes.length)
            .appendBytes(decodedBytes);
        merge(state, HyperLogLog.newInstance(bytesToDeserialize.slice()));
    }

    // This function tells us how to combine accumulators
    @CombineFunction
    public static void combine(@AggregationState HyperLogLogState state, @AggregationState HyperLogLogState otherState)
    {
        merge(state, otherState.getHyperLogLog());
    }

    // This function takes our state and merges in a new HLL.
    private static void merge(@AggregationState HyperLogLogState state, HyperLogLog input)
    {
        HyperLogLog previous = state.getHyperLogLog();
        if (previous == null) {
            state.setHyperLogLog(input);
            state.addMemoryUsage(input.estimatedMemorySize());
        }
        else {
            state.addMemoryUsage(-previous.estimatedMemorySize());
            previous.mergeWith(input);
            state.addMemoryUsage(previous.estimatedMemorySize());
        }
    }

    @OutputFunction(StandardTypes.VARCHAR)
    public static void output(@AggregationState HyperLogLogState state, BlockBuilder out)
    {
        HyperLogLog hll = state.getHyperLogLog();
        if (hll == null) {
            out.appendNull();
        }
        else {
            Slice output = hll.serialize();
            String encodedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output.getBytes());
            DynamicSliceOutput outSlice = new DynamicSliceOutput(encodedData.length());
            outSlice.appendBytes(encodedData.getBytes());
            VARCHAR.writeSlice(out, outSlice.slice());
        }
    }
}
```

I would love to hear any ideas as to what the issue might be, as I'm totally stumped.

Comment: I think for this type of questions you'd be better off asking on user group (https://groups.google.com/d/forum/presto-users) or Presto Slack (https://prestosql.io/community.html) (Slack is more effective for communication like this). However, it would be great if you could share full code and example query (e.g. using `VALUES`) showing the failure.

Comment: BTW why are you writing specialized HLL over base64-decoded data? You should be able to decode the data before passing to an existing HLL `merge` function. Writing decoding UDF (if one does not exist) will be simpler than writing an UDAF.

Comment: The honest answer to that is that I'm a bad Java programmer who isn't super familiar with the presto code base, but an ok scientist who knew how to cannibalize bits and pieces from various places to essentially get the thing working.

Comment: ...the other thing is that I built another system that may need to use lower precisions than the underlying types in Presto, and I need to be able to control that later, subject to engineering requirements.